# Jenkins Mail Sendning Failed

Tags: jenkins

I removed SSL check box , now am getting this exception

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you providing correct SMTP user and password credentials?